# MongoDB refuses to backup

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, rocket.chat

I have a MongoDB instance inside a docker container to run some local services and use `mongodump` to perform backups. Recently this backup process, and applications running on top, have broken because MongoDB no longer thinks its the master. I need the (up-to-date) backup contents to migrate the services to a new server. How can I get MongoDB to dump its database contents so I can redeploy the instance?

This is the command I run to perform a backup and the error message:

```
    mongodump --host "db" --port 27017 --db rocketchat                    
2019-05-17T11:28:59.950+0000    Failed: error counting rocketchat.rocketchat_apps_persistence: node is not in primary or recovering state
```

I've tried running a few variations of the mongodump command including treating the server as a secondary instance:

```
 mongodump --host "db" --port 27017 --readPreference secondaryPreferred
2019-05-17T11:16:23.066+0000    Failed: error counting admin.system.version: node is not in primary or recovering state
```

When I try to initiate the replicaset for the server, it already thinks it is initialized.

```
rs0:OTHER> rs.initiate()
{
    "info2" : "no configuration specified. Using a default configuration for the set",
    "me" : "1d70c5ced11b:27017",
    "info" : "try querying local.system.replset to see current configuration",
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "already initialized",
    "code" : 23,
    "codeName" : "AlreadyInitialized",
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1558063935, 1),
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1558063935, 1),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    }
}
```

Rsyncing the contents of the docker volume that contains the WiredTiger data unfortunately also doesn't' work. I end up with the same problem where the database errors out thinking that its not a master. Sadly this also means some low level backups (on top of the mongodump backups) also don't work.

Setup:

- Single MongoDB instance as a docker-compose service.
- Replicaset "rs0" for various databases with oplog.

Edit:

Result of rs.status() and rs.config()

```
rs0:OTHER> rs.status()
{
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1558063935, 1),
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Our replica set config is invalid or we are not a member of it",
    "code" : 93,
    "codeName" : "InvalidReplicaSetConfig",
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1558063935, 1),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    }
}

rs0:OTHER> rs.config()
{
    "_id" : "rs0",
    "version" : 1,
    "protocolVersion" : NumberLong(1),
    "writeConcernMajorityJournalDefault" : true,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "host" : "8d6d6fda7542:27017",
            "arbiterOnly" : false,
            "buildIndexes" : true,
            "hidden" : false,
            "priority" : 1,
            "tags" : {

            },
            "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
            "votes" : 1
        }
    ],
    "settings" : {
        "chainingAllowed" : true,
        "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : 2000,
        "heartbeatTimeoutSecs" : 10,
        "electionTimeoutMillis" : 10000,
        "catchUpTimeoutMillis" : -1,
        "catchUpTakeoverDelayMillis" : 30000,
        "getLastErrorModes" : {

        },
        "getLastErrorDefaults" : {
            "w" : 1,
            "wtimeout" : 0
        },
        "replicaSetId" : ObjectId("5ccfbd9f66a45fbddfa5c0f0")
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the output of `rs.status()` and `rs.conf()` ?

Comment: See edit. I noticed the replication set members had a docker id string instead of a real hostname. (db) I'm not sure of the mongo db commands to fix this.

Comment: Either use `rs.reconfig()`with force flag or set the id in `/etc/hosts`. Cheers.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rs.reconfig/